# How do format dates for data entry with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

So I have found tons of examples on how to use a date picker with angularjs.  That has been really helpful, but a datetime picker is not always appropriate.  (for example, people don't like to have to scroll back 20, 30, 40 years when trying to enter their date of birth ;)

So, I'm looking for an example of using angular to display and enter a date, with formatting, preferable using the angular's date formatting (so I can enter shortDate or "dd/MM/yyyy", etc).

I have the angular ui bootstrap library working, and it's great as a date picker.  Doesn't seem to work very well for direct data entry, though. Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

Ok, I have a plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/zreLCYjgTr7azWb6jf0I?p=preview

This demonstrates the unwanted behavior (when you click on the datetime, you get the picker, instead of just being able to enter a date.

The problem is, I don't understand why it happens.  If you just comment out line 3 in example.js, it stops popping up.  For the life of me, I don't understand why, because as nearly as I can tell, nothing calls that function.

here's the code (see the small example in plunker for all of the code).

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var DatepickerDemoCtrl = function ($scope) {
  $scope.today = function() { // comment this line, it all works
    $scope.dt = new Date();
  };
```

Comment: I use angular-ui-bootstrap's date picker, and I don't have any problem entering a date with my keyboard directly in the text field.

Comment: Funny thing -- you're right.  When I put the same markup into plnkr, it just works.  there must be some css that I'm inheriting somewhere along the way that is goofing up my picker in the app that I'm working on.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok, I have a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zreLCYjgTr7azWb6jf0I?p=preview .  I can get the behavior to start and stop (see my edit above), but I can't for the life of my figure out why the behavior changes (and since I don't know why, I can't see where the problem is in the real code).